# Visual Studio 11 Express for Windows 8 is only for WinRT?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-express, visual-studio-2012

Can I build regular .NET Applications in Visual Studio 11 Express for Windows 8?
I can't find the common project templates, like Console Application, Class Library or Windows Form Application.

Is there, or will there be, another Express for these kind of projects?

Answer (score 2):

No, the current beta VS11 Express edition only supports creating Metro apps.  Whether the RTM edition ever will support old style apps requires a crystal ball.  I doubt it.

You'll need to use the VS2010 Express edition if you want to create legacy apps.